# Strange division results (1023456789876543201 / 9 )

Tags: python, integer-division

I have the following piece of code with a pretty strange result.

**The code I:**

```
print("{:.2f}".format(1023456789876543201/9))
```

Result:

```
113717421097393696.00
```

**The code II:**

```
print("{:20d}".format(1023456789876543201//9))
```

Result:

```
113717421097393689
```

Why does Python returns wrong result in the first code sample? I know about floating point arithmetics but it seems for me that this is not the case.

Comment: "I know about floating point arithmetics but it seems for me that this is not the case." In fact, it is the case. Floats can only accurately represent integers up to 2^53. If you require precision, try using the fraction or decimal modules.

Comment: Maybe try using `x//y`.

Comment: The result of the division is `1.137174210973937e+17`, I presume the format is using this value which has lost accuracy.

Comment: Printing just the value being divided (i.e. leave off the `/9`) might make things clearer.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't quite see how that would help.

Comment: @SuperStormer: It shows that the value being divided can't even be displayed correctly.

Comment: @SuperStormer. Ok, it seems I've got it now. So all floats are stored in Python as "usual decimal" like in other languages like C#, Java with limited precisions, right? And Python use it's "special" number format (https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/) only for "true" integers, right?

Comment: I think @ScottHunter means, look at `1023456789876543201 / 1` and you'll see that the problem is precisely floating point.

Comment: @FrankYellin, yes, excatly. Division by 1 also returns "wrong" result.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. This questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469185/python-strange-division-results-1023456789876543201-9) is similar to this one.